Conway's Angel Problem: Strategy for Devil to catch $1-$Angel
I am learning about Conway's Angel Problem, which is in the image below. How can the Devil devise a strategy that will successfully capture the $1$-Angel, or an angel of power $1$, which is also a chess king? I know that the devil will need to create a fully enclosed area with the angel in it, but I'm not sure how this is possible. Thanks!

Note: In our case the Angel can move to any square in $1$ king move of its position.

See Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays, vol 3, chapter 19, "The King and the Consumer". There is a detailed strategy to trap the king in a $33\times 33$ square region, with lots of pictures.

Yep, Thanks. I checked it out.
